# Do I need a Google Cloud Platform account to embed Google Maps API into a website?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Firstly, I am sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question.

I made a website for a business and wanted to embed the business location using Google Maps API. All attempts to do this without opening a Google Cloud Platform account did not work. So I opened the Google Cloud Platform as a trial basis, and got it working. But now I am 7 days out from my Google Cloud Platform trial from ending.

Can someone please confirm or deny that I do or do not have to use Google Cloud Platform to simply embed Google Maps API?

Comment: I think you need to use Google account and Google Map is not API based, you can embed location in the website [link](https://www.embedgooglemap.net/en/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgPbWmN_j6gIVlYvICh23mwPYEAAYASAAEgIc1_D_BwE)

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot!